# How to delete unexpected data?

Tags: cnosdb

When I wrote the following data, unexpected results and unexpected tables appeared

```bash
curl -i -u "root:" -H "Accept: application/json" \
-XPOST "http://127.0.0.1:8902/api/v1/write?db=public" \
-d "motion,device_name=MotionSensor,location=Hallway motion_detected=1 1692772642000000000 1692772642000000000
security,device_name=DoorLock,location=FrontDoor locked=1,battery_level=38 1692772642000000000"
```

This is the content viewed by 'show tables':

```sql
 show tables;
+--------------------------------------+
| table_name                           |
+--------------------------------------+
| motion                               |
| 1692772642000000000                  |
| security                             |
+--------------------------------------+
```

But when I execute the command 'drop table "1692772642000000", it prompts:

```json
422 Unprocessable Entity, details: {"error_code":"030019","error_message":"Table not found: \"1692772642000000000\""}
```

So how can I delete these unexpected data?